# Java Spring - Lookup method injection for a List

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

I have a list of Objects currently autowired in my class, and I want to use the new spring lookup method injection so that every time this list is called, a list of new PROTOTYPE beans is returned (I want a new object every time as these are stateful beans and if I get the same object I end up with concurrency issues).

Here's the old implementation:

```
@Service
public class Service {

@Autowired
private List<HandlersInterface> handlers;

public void run() {
    // handle the action using one of the handlers
    handlers.get(0).doSomething();
}
```

This works fine, but every time I call service.run(), the list of handlers is the same so the same handler may be running multiple times causing trouble.

Moving to the spring lookup method injection, I found some tutorials for the easy scenario, but I can't find something that manages the whole list that I have. Something like:

```
@Service
public class Service {

public void run() {
List<HandlersInterface> handlers= lookUpHandlers();   
handlers.get(0).doSomething();
}

@Lookup
protected List<AppDataMessageHandler> lookUpHandlers() {
    return null; //I want this to be replaced by spring to provide a list of PROTOTYPE beans
}
```

}

Wondering if I somehow should be adding the list in my spring.xml file? (note that my list is a list of different @Component beans, implementing a common interface)

Answer (score 0):

My solution finally was:

spring.xml

```
  <util:list id="test" scope="prototype" value-type="CommonInterfaceOfBeans">
        <ref bean="bean1ClassName"/>
        <ref bean="bean2ClassName"/>
        <ref bean="bean3ClassName"/>
        <ref bean="bean4ClassName"/>
        <ref bean="bean5ClassName"/>
    </util:list>
```

and in my class:

```
@Service
public class Service {

public void run() {
List<CommonInterfaceOfBeans> handlers= lookUp();   
handlers.get(0).doSomething();
}

  @Lookup(value = "test")
    protected List<CommonInterfaceOfBeans> lookUp() {
        return null; //This gets replaced with list by Spring via cglib.
    }
```

I couldn't find a way to do the same thing without manually defining a list  in the spring.xml